# Selenium get(link) is not working properly

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

So I have written a very basic line of code that uses selenium to open a webpage.

```py
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.headless = False
chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
Path = "D:\Virtual Assistant\Database\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Path, options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url='www.youtube.com')
sleep(2)
```

This is the code that I am using.

This code used to work few days ago but it is no longer working and is showing this as an error.[The error that is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CFty.png)

I thought maybe there has been an update in the selenium package and I scoured the internet but couldn't find any solutions

Chrome version: v120.0.6099.225
Chrome driver version: v120.0.6099.109
Selenium version: v4.1.3

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package.
Using a different chrome driver version.
Nothing worked.

Comment: Change this line `driver.get(url='www.youtube.com')` to `driver.get(url='https://www.youtube.com')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your selenium software and webdriver is up to date. Then try like this

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')
sleep(2)
```